# Huge Number of consumers per ActiveMQ session

Tags: activemq-classic

I am making one session per connection per thread to activeMQ cluster. But I want to consume from hundreds of destinations. I do understand that if I only have one thread ( one session ), I can't consume messages from these destinations concurrently. I don't want to do that either. But I want to have hundreds of consumers per session which will in-turn be associated to hundreds of different destinations, is this a viable approach? Please also provide the reason of viability or non-viability.

PS : I don't want to do any heavy processing on the messages, so that's why only 1 thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session is not bound to a single thread - threading is a separate chapter. You can use a session in multiple threads (not recommended) and multiple sessions in a single thread. The session construct is more a thing to control transactions - i.e. commit and rollback messages in a transaction.

Anyway, you can use a single consumer to read multiple destinations. Simply put the destinations in a list like: `"my.first.queue,my.other.queue,my.last.queue"`. You can also read a queue using wildcards - `"my.>"`. would use all queues above.

This way, you can use a single thread and a single session to read from a large number of queues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Petter , can you also tell me if there are any performance issues with this model? Be assured that the the call back / message listener associated with this consumer is very lightweight and does nothing but submits a certain task to some executor.